# Read empty string as Null Athena

Tags: csv, amazon-athena

I want to create a table in Amazon Athena over csv file on s3. Csv file looks like

```
id,name,invalid
1,abc,
2,cba,y
```

Code for creating table looks like

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {schema}.{table_name} (
id int,
name string,
invalid string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ','
)
LOCATION '{s3}'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false','compressionType'='gzip')
```

So, my problem is Athena reads empty string as actually empty string but I'd like to see it like null. I haven't found any property for that in docs.

Answer (score 2):

`LazySimpleSerDe` will interpret `\N` as `NULL` by default, but you can configure it to use other strings with the `serialization.null.format` serde property.

For [this guide on CSV and Athena](https://athena.guide/articles/working-with-csv/) for more details.

Comment: So as far as I get it, it is impossible to set it up treat empty string as Null, isn't it?

Comment: That's how I remember it working, yes – but double check what happens if you set `serialization.null.format` to an empty string.